# turn <br> into line breaks using javascript (not php)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, line-breaks

I need to extract the text from a div with paragraphs and spans and other things and put it into a textarea. I need to load just the text, not the HTML.

For that, I can use:

```
loadtext = $('#mydiv').text();
```

However, I DO need to retain the line breaks.

For that, I'm doing:

```
loadtext = $('#mydiv').text().replace(/<br>/gm, '\r\n');
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, because when I load that text into a textarea, it's all flat with no line breaks. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Of course, `.text()` strips HTML, including `<br>`.

Comment: I am wondering why you get no line breaks - http://jsfiddle.net/evNKv/

Comment: @Xeano Your fiddle is incorrect, you pressed Enter before <br />, so this linebreak is actually in the textarea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('#mydiv').text()` has already been stripped of all HTML, including`<br>` elements, so this will not work. You need to modify the HTML of the `#mydiv` element and replace all `<br/>` elements, *then* retrieve the text.

```
$('#mydiv').find('br').each(function(){
    $(this).after("\n")
           .remove();
});
var loadtext = $("#mydiv").text();
```

Comment: Thank you! However the final working solution combined a bit of the answer below as well, i.e. creating an intermediate element like this: `newdiv = $('#mydiv').clone();` and then applying the above on that div. The reason was that by replacing the `<br>` with `\n` on the div itself, the div changed too, while I didn't need it to change, but just needed a text version of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to use an intermediate element that's never added to the document.

```
var html = $('#mydiv').html(); // e.g. '<p>line 1</p><br><br><p>line 2</p>'
var text = $('<div>').html(html.replace(/<br\/?>/g, '\n')).text();
/* text =
"line 1

line 2" 
*/
$('#mytextarea').text(text);
```

This supports `<br>` (HTML) and `<br/>`(XHTML).